# Recommendations for AMP on Desktop

Tags: amp-html

Let’s assume that someone shared an AMP URL (xyz.com/amp) in a Blog or Social media. 
What is the recommended user experience for a user who clicks on a shared AMP URL from a Desktop? 
Some options are:

a. Responsive AMP Page for a Desktop user (additional overhead and cant get desktop parity in many cases)

b. Redirect the user to a canonical page on Desktop (slow + not sure how it affects SEO)

c. Build AMP version of desktop page

Answer (score 0):

Please see responses for each option:

a. Responsive AMP Page for a Desktop user :
This is what we recommend as it keeps things simple and ensures that everyone can discover the AMP version.

b. Redirect the user to a canonical page on Desktop :
Some publishers do this, but it's tricky as they need to ensure that crawlers will always see the AMP page (other platforms might use their own crawler).

c. Build AMP version of desktop page : Some publishers have this setup.